como agregar fechas faltantes entre dos fechas en sql server?
Hola a todos quisiera saber si existe de alguna forma de poder rellenar fechas faltantes por medio de una consulta.
Tengo una consulta que agrupa por CIC(DNI) de clientes y por el mes del mas actual al mas viejo
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblsaldo2') is not null drop table #tblsaldo2 
SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CIC ORDER BY Mes desc) AS row_num,
   CIC,
   CONVERT(date,CONCAT(mes, '01')) as Mes,
   saldo INTO #tblsaldo2  
FROM  #tblsaldo

lo que basicamente me da como salida esto:

como se ve en estas agrupaciones, las meses no son secuenciales, por que no existe el mes que corresponde, quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de rellenar los meses faltantes en las filas con los mismos datos de agrupacion y con el "saldo" valor 0
como en la siguiente captura

gracias, esta pagina me ha salvado de mucho..

Básicamente necesitas:

Para cada cliente, encontrar la fecha inicial, la fecha final y el número de meses que hay entre ambas fechas, con el cual se puede calcular el número de registros que existirán en el conjunto de datos final para cada uno, que es el número de meses de diferencia más uno.
Con esta información, generar tantos registros como sean necesarios, tomando la fecha inicial e incrementando el mes de uno en uno en cada uno de ellos, hasta llegar a la fecha final
Finalmente, tomar este conjunto de datos como base y hacer un left join con el conjunto de datos original para encontrar el saldo correspondiente a los meses dónde si hay registro, teniendo el cuidado de colocar un cero en el saldo para los meses donde no hay registro.

Las piezas del rompecabezas serían:

Generador de números consecutivos: En SQL Server hay varias maneras de obtener números consecutivos de 1 a N, voy a utilizar uno de manera arbitraria, que es la consulta:
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) N from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN

Que nos va a devolver no menos de 1500 registros en una base de datos nueva y más a medida que tenga más y más tablas creadas. Considero que esto es suficiente, pero queda como ejercicio buscar la que más se adecúe (hay muchos ejemplos aquí mismo en SO).
El uso de CTE's, para facilitar ir desarrollando la lógica descrita en la sección anterior.
Convertir de manera temprana los datos almacenados en string en fechas. Para ello yo quitaría el guión, concatenaría '01' y luego me valdría de la función cast().
Con los datos ya como fechas, podemos valernos del soporte para aritmética de fechas del SQL Server para utilizar funciones como min(), max(), datediff() y dateadd() donde corresponda para lograr nuestro objetivo.
En mi ejemplo, hago uso del operador apply para realizar al vuelo la conversión a fecha del campo mes en cada registro que se va procesando en la consulta.

Uniendo todas las piezas, sobre los datos de ejemplo, la consulta:
;with
MinMax as (
select CIC, MIN(fecha) MinMes, MAX(fecha) MaxMes, DATEDIFF(month, MIN(fecha), MAX(fecha)) + 1 RegistrosMeses
  from #tblsaldo
       cross apply (select cast(substring(mes, 1, 4) + substring(mes, 6, 2) + '01' as date) fecha) as F
 group by CIC
)
,
Numeros as (
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) N from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
)
,
TodosLosMeses as (
select   CIC
       , DATEADD(MONTH, Numeros.N - 1, MinMax.MinMes) Fecha
       , substring(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, Numeros.N - 1, MinMax.MinMes), 23), 1, 7) Mes
  from MinMax
       inner join Numeros on Numeros.N <= MinMax.RegistrosMeses
)
select   ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t.CIC order by T.Fecha desc) row_num
       , t.CIC
       , t.Fecha
       , coalesce(s.saldo, 0) Saldo
  from TodosLosMeses t
       left join #tblsaldo s on s.CIC = t.CIC and s.mes = t.Mes
 order by CIC, Fecha desc

Me devuelve:
row_num              CIC         Fecha      Saldo
-------------------- ----------- ---------- -----------
1                    1215        2023-03-01 20
2                    1215        2023-02-01 0
3                    1215        2023-01-01 0
4                    1215        2022-12-01 39
5                    1215        2022-11-01 230
6                    1215        2022-10-01 100
7                    1215        2022-09-01 234
1                    2334        2022-05-01 10
2                    2334        2022-04-01 0
3                    2334        2022-03-01 0
4                    2334        2022-02-01 0
5                    2334        2022-01-01 50

Esperaría que los diferentes CTE's se auto-expliquen, pero si hace falta, la idea de cada uno es:

MinMax nos devuelve, para cada cliente, el primero y último mes y el cálculo del número de registros que hacen falta para ir del primero al último mes.
Numeros es el generador de números consecutivos, tal como se describió antes.
TodosLosMeses hace un join de los dos primeros para devolver el número de registros necesarios y para cada registro va calculando la fecha y, sobre esta, hace la conversión a cadena para tener un campo Mes que pueda usarse más adelante para encontrar el registro correspondiente en la tabla base.
Finalmente, la consulta principal toma los datos de TodosLosMeses, hace el left join con la tabla base. Para la columna saldo, me valgo de la función coalesce() para colocar un cero si no se encuentra coincidencia en la tabla de origen.

